# React App Some CSS Properties Gets Ignored

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

There's a weird bug in my application to causes some CSS properties to disappear. When I sign-in into my application, I used `<Redirect to="/home"`/> to go to my home page. And then some images disappear and some button are half the size they suppose to be. When I refresh the browser, page gets back to what it supposes to be. I'm using styled component mainly, and below are some pictures:

[after signin, wrong version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr2U3.png)

[after refresh page, correct version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Flty.jpg)

here is the complete code`https://github.com/aojiaooo/shopaholic-react-app`

To run the code, you have to change `SignIn.js` function below:

```
async function loginUser(credentials) {
  return "someRandomCookieOfYourChoice";
  //below was the original request to backend
  /**
  return await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/signin', credentials)
    .then(response => response.data.code === 0 ? response.data.data.value : null);
  */
}
```

Have being frustrated the whole day ... Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm a backend guy and this is my first day trying out React. Thanks in advance!

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

//general layout for shopaholic
export const SectionWrapper = styled.section`
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
`

// style for header
export const HeaderWrapper = styled.header`
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  .menu, .close{
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
  }

  .hello {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px 15px 15px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -50px;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 1000px){
    ul{
      position: fixed;
      top:0;
      left: -100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      background: white;
      z-index: 99;
      opacity: 0.97;
      transition: 0.5s linear;
      margin-left: -20px;
    }
    .menu, .close{
      display: block;
    }
    .close{
      position: relative;
    }
    ul.toggle{
      left: 0;
    }
  }
`

export const HeaderLogoLink = styled(Link)`
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
`

export const HeaderNavWrapper = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  padding-right: -100px;
  
  ul li a:hover{
    color: darkgray;
  }
  ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
`

// style for home page
export const ProductListWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
`

export const CardWrapper = styled.div`
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 20px #ddd;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  display: block;
`

export const CardInfoWrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
  }
  a:hover{
    color: darkblue;
  }
`

export const CardImageWrapper = styled.img`
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
`

export const CardTextWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: -5px 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`

export const CardTitleLinkWrapper = styled(Link)`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-family:  'Segoe UI',serif;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`

export const CardDetailLinkWrapper = styled(Link)`
  background:  #333;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`

// style for detail page
export const ProductDetailWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 50px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`

export const DetailImageWrapper = styled.img`
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 290px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 25px;
`

export const DetailInfoWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 290px;
  margin: 25px;
`

export const DetailTitleWrapper = styled.div`
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-block-start: 0.83em;
  margin-block-end: 0.83em;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family:  'Segoe UI',serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
`

export const DetailButtonWrapper = styled.button`
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
`

export const DetailTextWrapper = styled.div`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 10px 0;
`

// style for alert box
export const AlertTextWrapper = styled.div`
  font-family: '.AppleSystemUIFont', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this problem happens when running the app using
`npm start`

however, the css issue goes away when doing `npm run build` and then `serve -s build`

I guess production wise this is not a bug but rather something wrong with the development environment, in case any one in the future has this problem, one can try build the project and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but you may try this...

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// general layout for shopaholic
export const SectionWrapper = styled.section`
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
`;

// style for header
export const HeaderWrapper = styled.header`
  min-height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;

  .menu,
  .close {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
  }

  .hello {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 10px 15px 15px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -50px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    ul {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: -100%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      background: white;
      z-index: 99;
      opacity: 0.97;
      transition: 0.5s linear;
      margin-left: -20px;
    }
    .menu,
    .close {
      display: block;
    }
    .close {
      position: relative;
    }
    ul.toggle {
      left: 0;
    }
  }
`;

export const HeaderLogoLink = styled(Link)`
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 30px;
`;

export const HeaderNavWrapper = styled.nav`
  display: flex;
  padding-right: -100px;

  ul li a:hover {
    color: darkgray;
  }
  ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #555;
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
  ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
`;

// style for home page
export const ProductListWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;

export const CardWrapper = styled.div`
  min-width: 300px;
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 8px 20px #ddd;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  display: block;
`;

export const CardInfoWrapper = styled.div`
  margin: 10px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: darkblue;
  }
`;

export const CardImageWrapper = styled.img`
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
`;

export const CardTextWrapper = styled.div`
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: -5px 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`;

export const CardTitleLinkWrapper = styled(Link)`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', serif;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`;

export const CardDetailLinkWrapper = styled(Link)`
  background: #333;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`;

// style for detail page
export const ProductDetailWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 50px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
`;

export const DetailImageWrapper = styled.img`
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 290px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 25px;
`;

export const DetailInfoWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 290px;
  margin: 25px;
`;

export const DetailTitleWrapper = styled.div`
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-block-start: 0.83em;
  margin-block-end: 0.83em;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
`;

export const DetailButtonWrapper = styled.button`
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 35px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
`;

export const DetailTextWrapper = styled.div`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 10px 0;
`;

// style for alert box
export const AlertTextWrapper = styled.div`
  font-family: '.AppleSystemUIFont', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this work with styled component!! The use of the `!important` on the style that is being ignored, or overridden in react. In normal `css` i will do it this way:

```css
.selector{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

You can try this:

```
export const DetailButtonWrapper = styled.button`
  background: #333 !important ;
`;
```

Im not certain about this answer but yiu can try it. `!important` on the style which are not applying

Comment: Thank you for the insight! It still doesn't work. What I don't understand the most is why redirecting from one page to another causes this problem, but entering the url and visit directly doesn't.